# How to define a "callable" parameter in a Python docstring?

Tags: python, types, documentation, docstring, function-declaration

Consider an implementation of `filterNot` (basically the opposite of `filter`):

```
def filterNot(f, sequence):
    return filter(lambda x: not f(x), sequence)
```

The parameter `f` can be a "function" or a "method" or a `lambda` -- or even an object whose class defines `__call__`.

Now consider a line of docstring for this parameter:

```
:param ??? f: Should return True for each element to be abandoned
```

Now, what should go in place of **???** -- how should the *type* of parameter `f` be referred to in a docstring. `callable` is the obvious choice (and what I would dictate if I were calling the shots :P) but is there an established convention?

Comment: It's worth noting that functions, methods, and lambdas are all just functions produced through different methods - they are nothing special in their own right.

Comment: @200OK That's not really relevant to what the question is asking.

Comment: `callable` seems fine to me and is probably best -- If your documentation generating engine doesn't like that, `function` is probably the next best thing.  After all, in python, it's assumed that  the object just needs to _behave_ like whatever type the function is documented to take.

Comment: @Lattyware Informally, they are all functions, in the sense that they are callable. However, there are distinct types `function` (created by `lambda` expressions and `def` statements), `instancemethod` (either an instance or class method), and `builtin_function_or_method` (implemented directly in C, rather than by Python code). Further, any object whose type/class defines the `__call__` method is a callable without being any of the previously mentioned types. Hence, it's worth having a term that encompasses *all* of them.

Comment: @chepner Oh, indeed, I'm not saying that there is no need for a general term, I was just pointing out that functions and lambdas are identical items, just constructed through different means. (And methods are essentially just decorated functions). It wasn't intended as a question-changer, just a note of interest.

Comment: Not to be too pedantic (which means I *am* being too pedantic :), a method is not just a decorated function. It is a distinct type that, among other attributes, contains a reference to a callable object and a reference (which may be `None`, in the case of an unbound method) to an object (in the case of a bound method).

Comment: @chepner it probably doesn't help I'm thinking of 3.x where unbound methods don't exist, making my comparison more valid.

Comment: @Lattyware Oh, I hadn't considered what the differences between 2.x and 3.x were. Looks like I have some reading to do!

Answer (score 11):

Yes, the term callable is the one to use here.

[The abstract base class `Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable) exists in `collections.abc` - abstract base classes can be best thought of as interfaces (although more like they dynamic ones in Go than those in Java, for example) - they define an interface, and any class that has the given functions is defined as inheriting from that abstract base class (whether they did so explicitly or not) - this means anything you would usefully pass into a function like this would be a subclass of `Callable`, making the use of the term completely correct here. Just as you might say `Iterable`.

It is definitely the term used by most people in when talking informally about Python code, and anyone reading your code should understand what you mean.

The `callable()` built-in (that got removed for a while in 3.x, then added back) does the check for function-like objects, and this further reinforces the name as the best choice where you are looking for function-like objects.

Comment: It sounds to me like the answer is "no", but you agree that "callable" is the best term to use... :-/

Comment: @chrisw. The question asked was what to or in a docstring where you want a function-like object - callable is the right thing for that.

Comment: I'm asking if there's an "official" or standardized way of doing this (e.g., in a PIP)... It doesn't sound as if there is. That said, I agree that "callable" makes more sense than "function" or anything else I can think of.

Comment: @ChrisW. Well, it's not 'official' that you should use 'str' when you want a string - giving the name of the type (in this case abstract base class), is pretty much the assumed use here.